# How to get type="xs:date" instead of type="xs:dateTime"

Tags: java, datetime, jax-ws, cxf, jaxb2

I'm creating a bottom-up web service from a java class using Apache CXF

In the java class, I am using java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar for two fields

When the WSDL is generated by CXF, both the elements have type="xs:dateTime". How do I generate the element to have a type of type="xs:date" instead?

I am using JAXB2.2.5

Comment: Show your source code. How do you annotated the field? Was it @XmlSchemaType(name="date")?

Comment: @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = false, name = "purchaseFromDate")
 protected Calendar purchaseFromDate;

Comment: Can you try @XmlSchemaType(name="date")?

Comment: Working.  Please move this to the Answer so that I can mark it as Answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override this behavior with `@XmlSchemaType(name="date")` annotation.

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchemaType.html)

> Maps a Java type to a simple schema built-in type.